# Stripe redirectToCheckout with php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm creating successfully a subscription for a customer with the redirectToCheckout mehtod.
I'm creating the Stripe Session as following

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'locale' => 'de',
            'line_items' => [[
                'price' => env('STRIPE_PRICE'),
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'subscription',
            'success_url' => $success_url,
            'cancel_url' => $cancel_url,
        ]);
```

But I have two problems. This method is creating a new customer for me, unfortunately I need to set the language for the customer to German (not happening currently). Furthermore I need to define the tax for the line_items but didn't succeeded as suggested on the stripe docs for creating a Session Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a specific Customer (rather than have Checkout create one for you), you need to create it [0] before the CheckoutSession. Then you pass the Customer's id as `CheckoutSession.customer` [1].

For taxes, you can specify the TaxRates in `CheckoutSession.subscription_data.default_tax_rates`[2].

(pardon the dot notation, as this isn't PHP-specific and thus can be applied to any of Stripe's API libraries)

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-default_tax_rates